# It is a delicacy to

Tags: meaning, to-infinitive

Does it make sense to say this phrase?

> It is a **delicacy** to have a banana in this restaurant

This was supposedly written by a native speaker.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Let's go with "supposedly". What are you trying to say? The banana is a delicacy there?

Comment: Did you look up [the meaning of *delicacy*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/delicacy)?  It normally means something like "a rare and expensive food", so a banana could be a delicacy, but it doesn't make sense to say that *to have* a banana is a delicacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe he/she was a native Spanish speaker and not an English one.

Let me explain. We got these words in Spanish

**[delicia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C7XUpbV)**

> (1) Placer muy intenso del ánimo. [EN: **[delight](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/delight)**]
>
> (2) Aquello que causa delicia. [Something that causes delight]

The second can be applied to food, being its English equivalent **[delicacy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/delicacy)**

> something especially rare or expensive that is good to eat

So I think that what the supposedly native may be meaning is

> It is a **delight** to have a banana in this restaurant. It's a **delicacy**
>   [the banana]